# Ubuntu Update Manager package operation failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu-11.10

I"m trying to update my Ubuntu, and previously my internet connection went out when trying to update, now all i get is this error message:

```
Package operation failed

The installation or removal of a software package failed.
```

EDIT: error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-     i386/Packages  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages - open (28: No space left on device) [IP: 74.125.224.68 80]
```

Note, i have over 5gb left on the disk...

Error code after running:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

> (Reading database ... 176208 files and directories currently installed.)
>   Preparing to replace tzdata-java 2011k-0ubuntu0.11.04 (using .../tzdata-java_2011l-0ubuntu0.11.04_all.deb) ...
>   Unpacking replacement tzdata-java ...
>   dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/tzdata-java_2011l-0ubuntu0.11.04_all.deb (--unpack):
>    unable to create `/usr/share/javazi/Pacific/Tarawa.dpkg-new' (while processing`./usr/share/javazi/Pacific/Tarawa'): No space left on device
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
>                                                                                 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
>   Preparing to replace tzdata 2011k-0ubuntu0.11.04 (using .../tzdata_2011l-0ubuntu0.11.04_all.deb) ...
>   Unpacking replacement tzdata ...
>   dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/tzdata_2011l-0ubuntu0.11.04_all.deb (--unpack):
>    unable to create `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Yap.dpkg-new' (while processing`./usr/share/zoneinfo/Pacific/Yap'): No space left on device
>   No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
>                                                                                 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/tzdata-java_2011l-0ubuntu0.11.04_all.deb
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/tzdata_2011l-0ubuntu0.11.04_all.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Can you give more details as to this error? This is VERY general here.

Comment: try ```sudo apt-get update```

Comment: it just seems to donwnload files and not do anything...

Comment: update won't do anything itself, other than update what you need to upgrade. Now do a sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Try to put proxy settings correctly to your network conection.